# How to position an image in the bottom of a side(left) div?

Tags: html, css, image, position

My title is not a best way to describe what is a problem.

I have two divs. Left div and a right div and I know how to make them to be the same height but the problem is that I have to place an image in a bottom of the left div and the image must always be in the bottom if height in the right div changes.

I hope that you understand what I have asked.

Comment: share your code please??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Use a background image on the left div and position it bottom left.

```
div.left-div {
  background: url(image.jpg) bottom left no-repeat;
  padding-bottom: 200px; /* change this to the height of the image */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use absolute positioning. But a more modern approach is to use `flexbox` together with `margin-top: auto;`.

```css
#example
{
  display: flex;
}

#one
{
  display: flex;
}

#one img
{
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="example">
<div id="one">
  <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=350&h=150" />
</div>
<div id="two">
This div has a big height<br />
This div has a big height<br />
This div has a big height<br />
This div has a big height<br />
This div has a big height<br />
This div has a big height<br />
This div has a big height<br />
This div has a big height<br />
This div has a big height<br />
This div has a big height<br />
This div has a big height<br />
This div has a big height<br />
This div has a big height<br />
This div has a big height<br />
This div has a big height<br />
This div has a big height<br />
This div has a big height
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `position` like below code if you use image in html and if you use background image then go with @Aaron answer.

```css
*{margin:0;padding:0;}
  .wrap{
    min-height:300px;
    width:450px;
    position:relative;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    padding-bottom:150px;
    
  }
  .innerBox{
    margin-bottom:10px;
  }
  figure{
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right:0;
  }
  figure img{
    display:block;
  }
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="innerBox">
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.<br/>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.<br/>
     exercitationepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </div>
    
    <figure>
      <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=350&h=150">
    </figure>
  </div>
```

I hope it will helps you.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but when I make a new html page I always have to  adjust height of that left div so that image is in bottom. I need something that always place an image in bottom so I don't need to adjust height every time.